# Xpath - select first occurence of node with specific type

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to select all of the first occurrences of a specific type in the following structure:

```
<div class="jobs-list">
    <div class="job-listing">
        <h3>Title1</h3>
        <span class="organization">
            <a href="https://www.domain1.org/" target="_blank">Org1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="location">Loc1</span>
        <div class="description">
            desc1
            <a href="https://www.domain1-1.org/" target="_blank">https://www.domain1-1.org/</a>
            <span class="list-date">Posted on: 01/19/2022</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="job-listing">
        <h3>Title2</h3>
        <span class="organization">
            <a href="https://www.domain2.org/" target="_blank">Org2</a>
        </span>
        <span class="location">Loc2</span>
        <div class="description">
            desc2
            <a href="https://www.domain2.org/" target="_blank">https://www.domain2.org/</a>
            <span class="list-date">Posted on: 01/18/2022</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="job-listing">
        <h3>Title3</h3>
        <span class="organization">
            <a href="https://www.domain3.org/" target="_blank">Org3</a>
        </span>
        <span class="location">Loc3</span>
        <div class="description">
            desc3            
            <a href="mailto:user@domain3.org">user@domain3.org</a>
            <span class="list-date">Posted on: 01/19/2022</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="job-listing">
        <h3>TItle4</h3>
        <span class="organization">Org4</span>
        <span class="location">Loc4</span>
        <div class="description">
            desc4
            <a href="mailto:user@domain4.org">user@domain4.org</a>
            <a href="https://www.domain4.org/" target="_blank">https://www.domain4.org/</a>
            <a href="https://www.domain4-1.org/" target="_blank">https://www.domain4-1.org/</a>
            <span class="list-date">Posted on: 01/06/2022</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Specifically, I need the result to be the following:

```
https://www.domain1.org/
https://www.domain2.org/
https://www.domain3.org/
https://www.domain4.org/
```

Which should be the first `a/@href` under each `div[@class='job-listing']`, but I'm not sure how to express that. Some things to note:

- The `<a>` is always two nodes under the root (job-listing)
- The first `<a>` isn't always correct (only looking for http), but I can filter those out easily enough; I'm caught up on how to select the node, not filtering for the content or anything like that.
- I need the value of `a/@href`, not the contents of `<a>`.

Thanks!

Comment: Before you can express it in XPath, you need to work out how to express it in English. Clearly "the first a/@href under each div[@class='job-listing']" isn't right,  because for the 4th job-listing that would be `mailto:user@domain4.org`. So I can't help you because the requirement isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//div[@class='job-listing']/descendant::a[1]` gives you the first `a` descendant of each of those `div`s, if you want to add the check then use e.g. `//div[@class='job-listing']/descendant::a[starts-with(@href, 'http')][1]`.

If you need the `href` attribute node use `//div[@class='job-listing']/descendant::a[starts-with(@href, 'http')][1]/@href`. Note that some default serialization for XSLT or XQuery doesn't allow you to serialize a sequence of standalone attribute nodes but in XPath 2 or 3 you can of course use e.g. `//div[@class='job-listing']/descendant::a[starts-with(@href, 'http')][1]/@href/string()` to get a sequence of attribute values instead.

Comment: I've tried both of these, neither work in practice nor on http://xpather.com.  Sorry, I should have been more specific; I'm looking for the value of `@href`. I will edit the question to reflect that. This is close, but the problem is pretty clear: `//div[@class='job-listing']/descendant::a[1]/@href[not(contains(.,'mailto'))]` - domain4 is left out because the first `@href` is a mailto.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't understand how to filter first, that worked. So the `starts-with` is working on the `a` node, and I can apply any attribute to it? Or could I do another `descendant::` and check the contents of nodes further down? This is great. Thanks again.

Comment: Inside of a predicate, you can use any XPath navigation/expression, including attribute, descendant, ancestor, preceding-sibling and so forth axis.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a more class-based selector:

```
//span[@class="organization"]//a/@href 
| 
//div[@class="description"][not(preceding-sibling::span/a)]
//a[contains(@href,"http")][1]/@href
```

Select links under `organization` (`A`) and first `http` link under `description` that doesn't meet `A`

See [live tester link](http://granitosaur.us/xpath-tester/?html=PGRpdiBjbGFzcz0iam9icy1saXN0Ij4KICAgIDxkaXYgY2xhc3M9ImpvYi1saXN0aW5nIj4KICAgICAgICA8aDM%2BVGl0bGUxPC9oMz4KICAgICAgICA8c3BhbiBjbGFzcz0ib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uIj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZG9tYWluMS5vcmcvIiB0YXJnZXQ9Il9ibGFuayI%2BT3JnMTwvYT4KICAgICAgICA8L3NwYW4%2BCiAgICAgICAgPHNwYW4gY2xhc3M9ImxvY2F0aW9uIj5Mb2MxPC9zcGFuPgogICAgICAgIDxkaXYgY2xhc3M9ImRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgZGVzYzEKICAgICAgICAgICAgPGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZG9tYWluMS0xLm9yZy8iIHRhcmdldD0iX2JsYW5rIj5odHRwczovL3d3dy5kb21haW4xLTEub3JnLzwvYT4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPHNwYW4gY2xhc3M9Imxpc3QtZGF0ZSI%2BUG9zdGVkIG9uOiAwMS8xOS8yMDIyPC9zcGFuPgogICAgICAgIDwvZGl2PgogICAgPC9kaXY%2BCiAgICA8ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSJqb2ItbGlzdGluZyI%2BCiAgICAgICAgPGgzPlRpdGxlMjwvaDM%2BCiAgICAgICAgPHNwYW4gY2xhc3M9Im9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiI%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxhIGhyZWY9Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmRvbWFpbjIub3JnLyIgdGFyZ2V0PSJfYmxhbmsiPk9yZzI8L2E%2BCiAgICAgICAgPC9zcGFuPgogICAgICAgIDxzcGFuIGNsYXNzPSJsb2NhdGlvbiI%2BTG9jMjwvc3Bhbj4KICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSJkZXNjcmlwdGlvbiI%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgIGRlc2MyCiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxhIGhyZWY9Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmRvbWFpbjIub3JnLyIgdGFyZ2V0PSJfYmxhbmsiPmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmRvbWFpbjIub3JnLzwvYT4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPHNwYW4gY2xhc3M9Imxpc3QtZGF0ZSI%2BUG9zdGVkIG9uOiAwMS8xOC8yMDIyPC9zcGFuPgogICAgICAgIDwvZGl2PgogICAgPC9kaXY%2BCiAgICA8ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSJqb2ItbGlzdGluZyI%2BCiAgICAgICAgPGgzPlRpdGxlMzwvaDM%2BCiAgICAgICAgPHNwYW4gY2xhc3M9Im9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiI%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxhIGhyZWY9Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmRvbWFpbjMub3JnLyIgdGFyZ2V0PSJfYmxhbmsiPk9yZzM8L2E%2BCiAgICAgICAgPC9zcGFuPgogICAgICAgIDxzcGFuIGNsYXNzPSJsb2NhdGlvbiI%2BTG9jMzwvc3Bhbj4KICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSJkZXNjcmlwdGlvbiI%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgIGRlc2MzICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxhIGhyZWY9Im1haWx0bzp1c2VyQGRvbWFpbjMub3JnIj51c2VyQGRvbWFpbjMub3JnPC9hPgogICAgICAgICAgICA8c3BhbiBjbGFzcz0ibGlzdC1kYXRlIj5Qb3N0ZWQgb246IDAxLzE5LzIwMjI8L3NwYW4%2BCiAgICAgICAgPC9kaXY%2BCiAgICA8L2Rpdj4KICAgIDxkaXYgY2xhc3M9ImpvYi1saXN0aW5nIj4KICAgICAgICA8aDM%2BVEl0bGU0PC9oMz4KICAgICAgICA8c3BhbiBjbGFzcz0ib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uIj5Pcmc0PC9zcGFuPgogICAgICAgIDxzcGFuIGNsYXNzPSJsb2NhdGlvbiI%2BTG9jNDwvc3Bhbj4KICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSJkZXNjcmlwdGlvbiI%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgIGRlc2M0CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxhIGhyZWY9Im1haWx0bzp1c2VyQGRvbWFpbjQub3JnIj51c2VyQGRvbWFpbjQub3JnPC9hPgogICAgICAgICAgICA8YSBocmVmPSJodHRwczovL3d3dy5kb21haW40Lm9yZy8iIHRhcmdldD0iX2JsYW5rIj5odHRwczovL3d3dy5kb21haW40Lm9yZy88L2E%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxhIGhyZWY9Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmRvbWFpbjQtMS5vcmcvIiB0YXJnZXQ9Il9ibGFuayI%2BaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZG9tYWluNC0xLm9yZy88L2E%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxzcGFuIGNsYXNzPSJsaXN0LWRhdGUiPlBvc3RlZCBvbjogMDEvMDYvMjAyMjwvc3Bhbj4KICAgICAgICA8L2Rpdj4KICAgIDwvZGl2Pgo8L2Rpdj4%3D&xpath=Ly9zcGFuW0BjbGFzcz0ib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uIl0vL2EvQGhyZWYgfCAvL2RpdltAY2xhc3M9ImRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIl1bbm90KHByZWNlZGluZy1zaWJsaW5nOjpzcGFuL2EpXS8vYVtjb250YWlucyhAaHJlZiwiaHR0cCIpXVsxXS9AaHJlZg%3D%3D#editor)

[image]